# What is this bridge like component?

Tags: pcb, identification, surface-mount

As I was looking at some Texas Instruments evaluation module, FDC2214EVM to be precise, I found a component unknown to me:

[image: Component image]

Comment: Looks like a GND clip

Comment: It's one of those components that when you need one, you'll instantly recognize what it's for when you see it.

Comment: Can;t tell you how many times my 'scope probe alligators have searched for one of those to bite.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just a test point for easily attaching a scope probe ground.

The silk screen indicates it is connected to ground, there may be some for other signals although they are usually just small round pads for manual probing.

The ground clip of the scope is always the tricky one to find a good connection for when probing a board.

Here's another similar type:

[Test point](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/keystone-electronics/5019/3907344?utm_adgroup=Test%20Points&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Test%20and%20Measurement_NEW&utm_term=&utm_content=Test%20Points&gclid=Cj0KCQiAqbyNBhC2ARIsALDwAsBdhmlu1a9duKNQvUgEyY3VbVdSb877fkI0Lf2i77OwU5k_FY1dSbcaAiyEEALw_wcB)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a test point, though a fairly unusual one.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about it. The last time I looked at a suppliers catalogue, they were shown right next to the ones shown in @KevinWhite's answer.

Comment: My experience of test points has been either through hole components or just plain pads on the board. I don't recall seeing surface mounted testpoint loops much, but maybe I just haven't looked at enough recent devboards.